# How to wrap text for <af:commandLink> in Oracle ADF 11g application

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracle-adf

I am building a `Fusion Web Application` using `Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3`

How to wrap text for `<af:commandLink>`?

In `<af:outputText>` component there is propriety called `noWrap` where I can choose warp the text or not.

In my case I have a lengthy title which defined as `<af:commandLink>` and I want to wrap around the link text, but there is no such propriety.

Note: I do not want to `sub-string` the value or doing it in Database level, instead I want to solve this issue in application level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just style it with css, either inline or via skin class.
`"white-space:nowrap;"` or `"white-space:normal;"`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to nest the outputText into the command link.

Thusly

```
<af:commandLink> <af:outputText value="Wrapped Text Line"/> </af:commandLink>
```